# How to call a recursive function in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

In my `componentList` I am going to have multiple objects.

```
if ($scope.componentList && $scope.componentList.length > 0) {
       angular.forEach($scope.componentList, function(admincomp, index) {
          $scope.validateAdmincomp(admincomp, index);
       });
 }



$scope.validateAdmincomp = function(admincomp, index) {
     for (var key in admincomp) {
       if (key !== "$$hashKey" && admincomp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
           angular.element(document.querySelector('#' + key + index)).removeClass("errorhilight");
                }
            }
       if (admincomp.componentName == undefined || admincomp.componentName == "") {    
             angular.element(document.querySelector('#componentName' + index)).addClass("errorhilight");
                isValidData = false;
            }
};
```

The `$scope.componentList` format is going to be as follows

```
[
  {
    "revision": 0,  
    "componentName": "abc",
    "componentIdentification": "abc",
    "componentType": "1",
    "componentState": "1",
    "componentUrl": null,
    "componentId": "214",
    "rowId": "3",
    "items": [
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "efg",
        "componentIdentification": "efg",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "215",
        "rowId": "3.1",
        "items": null,
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "16",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      }
    ],
    "componentStateId": 0,
    "ctastatus": 0,
    "actionId": "37",
    "actionToPerform": "1"
  },
  {
    "revision": 0,
    "componentName": "hij",
    "componentIdentification": "hij",
    "componentType": "1",
    "componentState": "1",
    "componentUrl": null,
    "componentId": "206",
    "rowId": "1",
    "items": [
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "klm",
        "componentIdentification": "klm",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "207",
        "rowId": "1.1",
        "items": [
          {
            "revision": 0,
            "componentName": "nop",
            "componentIdentification": "nop",
            "componentType": "2",
            "componentState": "1",
            "componentUrl": null,
            "componentId": "208",
            "rowId": "1.1.1",
            "items": [
              {
                "revision": 0,
                "componentName": "qrs",
                "componentIdentification": "qrs",
                "componentType": "2",
                "componentState": "1",
                "componentUrl": null,
                "componentId": "209",
                "rowId": "1.1.1.1",
                "items": null,
                "componentStateId": 0,
                "ctastatus": 0,
                "actionId": "26",
                "actionToPerform": "1"
              },
              {
                "revision": 0,
                "componentName": "tuv",
                "componentIdentification": "tuv",
                "componentType": "2",
                "componentState": "1",
                "componentUrl": null,
                "componentId": "210",
                "rowId": "1.1.1.2",
                "items": null,
                "componentStateId": 0,
                "ctastatus": 0,
                "actionId": "5",
                "actionToPerform": "1"
              }
            ],
            "componentStateId": 0,
            "ctastatus": 0,
            "actionId": "25",
            "actionToPerform": "1"
          }
        ],
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "1",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      }
    ],
    "componentStateId": 0,
    "ctastatus": 0,
    "actionId": "37",
    "actionToPerform": "1"
  },
  {
    "revision": 0,
    "componentName": "wxy",
    "componentIdentification": "wxy",  
    "componentType": "1",
    "componentState": "1",
    "componentUrl": null,
    "componentId": "211",
    "rowId": "2",
    "items": [
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "zab",
        "componentIdentification": "zab",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "212",
        "rowId": "2.1", 
        "items": null,
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "7",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      },
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "cde",
        "componentIdentification": "cde",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "213",
        "rowId": "2.2",
        "items": null,
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "12",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      }
    ],
    "componentStateId": 0,
    "ctastatus": 0,
    "actionId": "37",
    "actionToPerform": "1"
  }
]
```

In the above code the parents are only validated as the forEach loop is considering only the `$scope.componentList` list and not considering the inside `items[]` list. I want to call `validateAdmincomp` function for each object.
How can I call `validateAdmincomp` function forEach object.

Comment: Is `validateAdmincomp` your code? If yes, then you can modify it to validate a property and call itself if it's an object.

Comment: Do you want to only use forEach()?

Comment: share you validateAdmincomp function code.

Comment: @Md.AtiqulIslam Not like that

Comment: @GauravSrivastava  I have added the validateAdmincomp function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below code. Move your iteration logic to a method (recursive method)

```
if ($scope.componentList && $scope.componentList.length > 0) {
    validateList($scope.componentList) // starting point to iterate and validate the list
}

var validateList = function(list) {
    angular.forEach(list, function(admincomp, index) {
        $scope.validateAdmincomp(admincomp, index); // considering this method is doing some other validations
        if (admincomp.items && admincomp.items.lenght > 0)
            validateList(admincomp.items); // method calling itself
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you are looking for this or not. It will iterate each key and if its an object and not null it will call the function with the object.

```js
var list = [
  {
    "revision": 0,  
    "componentName": "abc",
    "componentIdentification": "abc",
    "componentType": "1",
    "componentState": "1",
    "componentUrl": null,
    "componentId": "214",
    "rowId": "3",
    "items": [
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "efg",
        "componentIdentification": "efg",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "215",
        "rowId": "3.1",
        "items": null,
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "16",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      }
    ],
    "componentStateId": 0,
    "ctastatus": 0,
    "actionId": "37",
    "actionToPerform": "1"
  },
  {
    "revision": 0,
    "componentName": "hij",
    "componentIdentification": "hij",
    "componentType": "1",
    "componentState": "1",
    "componentUrl": null,
    "componentId": "206",
    "rowId": "1",
    "items": [
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "klm",
        "componentIdentification": "klm",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "207",
        "rowId": "1.1",
        "items": [
          {
            "revision": 0,
            "componentName": "nop",
            "componentIdentification": "nop",
            "componentType": "2",
            "componentState": "1",
            "componentUrl": null,
            "componentId": "208",
            "rowId": "1.1.1",
            "items": [
              {
                "revision": 0,
                "componentName": "qrs",
                "componentIdentification": "qrs",
                "componentType": "2",
                "componentState": "1",
                "componentUrl": null,
                "componentId": "209",
                "rowId": "1.1.1.1",
                "items": null,
                "componentStateId": 0,
                "ctastatus": 0,
                "actionId": "26",
                "actionToPerform": "1"
              },
              {
                "revision": 0,
                "componentName": "tuv",
                "componentIdentification": "tuv",
                "componentType": "2",
                "componentState": "1",
                "componentUrl": null,
                "componentId": "210",
                "rowId": "1.1.1.2",
                "items": null,
                "componentStateId": 0,
                "ctastatus": 0,
                "actionId": "5",
                "actionToPerform": "1"
              }
            ],
            "componentStateId": 0,
            "ctastatus": 0,
            "actionId": "25",
            "actionToPerform": "1"
          }
        ],
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "1",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      }
    ],
    "componentStateId": 0,
    "ctastatus": 0,
    "actionId": "37",
    "actionToPerform": "1"
  },
  {
    "revision": 0,
    "componentName": "wxy",
    "componentIdentification": "wxy",  
    "componentType": "1",
    "componentState": "1",
    "componentUrl": null,
    "componentId": "211",
    "rowId": "2",
    "items": [
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "zab",
        "componentIdentification": "zab",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "212",
        "rowId": "2.1", 
        "items": null,
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "7",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      },
      {
        "revision": 0,
        "componentName": "cde",
        "componentIdentification": "cde",
        "componentType": "2",
        "componentState": "1",
        "componentUrl": null,
        "componentId": "213",
        "rowId": "2.2",
        "items": null,
        "componentStateId": 0,
        "ctastatus": 0,
        "actionId": "12",
        "actionToPerform": "1"
      }
    ],
    "componentStateId": 0,
    "ctastatus": 0,
    "actionId": "37",
    "actionToPerform": "1"
  }
]

function rec(obj){
 for (let key in obj){
  if(typeof obj[key] == "object" && obj[key]){
  console.log(key);
    rec(obj[key]);
  }
 }
}

list.forEach(function(o){
rec(o);
})
```